# Problema para realizar require de um arquivo

Tags: php, apache

[image: Este é o erro]

[image: Este é o meu código]

Este é meu erro e código respectivamente. Eu consigo fazer includes em outros arquivos, só no config.php que não!

Alguém tem uma solução?

OBS: É bom ressaltar que eu já tentei tirar o '.;' que está à frente do 'C:\'.
E eu não tenho nenhum caminho para C:\php e muito menos o C:\php\pear.

Obrigado!

Comment: Não coloques imagens, neste caso podes deixar a de erro mas coloca o de php mesmo por escrito sff. Bem vindo

Comment: Não tenho o pear instalado. Miguel, obrigado, sou iniciante :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de um tempo passei aqui, já tinha resolvido, mas vou colocar a resposta para quem não achou solução ainda.

```
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/imob/');
//este funciona
require_once('../helpers/functions.php');
//este não funciona
require_once(str_replace('http://', '', BASE_URL).'restrito/helpers/functions.php');
```

- config.php fica em: localhost/imob/restrito/config/config.php
- functions.php fica em: localhost/imob/restrito/helpers/functions.php